# Sum numbers by letter in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
[ ('A',100), ('B',50), ('A',50), ('B',20), ('C',10) ]
```

I am trying to sum up all numbers that have the same letter. I.e. I want to output

```
[('A', 150), ('B', 70), ('C',10)]
```

I have tried using set to get the unique values but then when I try and compare the first elements to the set I get

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Any quick solutions to match the numbers by letter?

Comment: Based on your error message you are trying to add together a string and an integer, which is illegal without typecasting.

Comment: Using a set to extract unique values. Then using a nested loop to find the values of the numbers that match the set and then sum these. I know how to do it with great computational expense, but if I ever had a few million entries it would take forever

Comment: It's not hw I have a huge data set I need to perform a computation on and my approach was way too slow

Comment: People often get lost answering the specific question directly and don't address the underlying issue. Why would you ever end up with a list of such tuples? There are much better ways to handle the data in Python (defaultdicts for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one(and a half?)-liner: group by letter (for which you need to sort before), then take the sum of the second entries of your tuples.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [('A', 100), ('B', 50), ('A', 50), ('B', 20), ('C', 10)]
res = [(k, sum(map(itemgetter(1), g)))
       for k, g in groupby(sorted(data, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))]
print(res)
// => [('A', 150), ('B', 70), ('C', 10)]
```

The above is O(n log n) — sorting is the most expensive operation. If your input list is truly large, you might be better served by the following O(n) approach:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [('A', 100), ('B', 50), ('A', 50), ('B', 20), ('C', 10)]

d = defaultdict(int)
for letter, value in data:
    d[letter] += value
res = list(d.items())
print(res)
// => [('B', 70), ('C', 10), ('A', 150)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for k, num in items:
        c[k] += num


>>> c.items()
[('A', 150), ('C', 10), ('B', 70)]
```

Less efficient (but nicer looking) one liner version:

```
>>> Counter(k for k, num in items for i in range(num)).items()
[('A', 150), ('C', 10), ('B', 70)]
```

Comment: downvote probably due to seeing  "Counter" and "sum" and not reading how you solved summing instead of counting it :) have another one

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, firstly create a dictionary to store your values. Then convert the `dict` object to `tuple list` using `.items()` Below is the sample code on how to achieve this:

```
my_list = [ ('A',100), ('B',50), ('A',50), ('B',20), ('C',10) ]
my_dict = {}
for key, val in my_list:
    if key in my_dict:
        my_dict[key] += val
    else:
        my_dict[key] = val

my_dict.items()
# Output: [('A', 150), ('C', 10), ('B', 70)]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this: (assuming `a` is the name of the tuple you have provided)

```
letters_to_numbers = {}
for i in a:
    if i[0] in letters_to_numbers:
        letters_to_numbers[i[0]] += i[1]
    else:
        letters_to_numbers[i[0]] = i[1]
b = letters_to_numbers.items()
```

The elements of the resulting tuple `b` will be in no particular order.

Answer (score 1):

What is generating the list of tuples? Is it you? If so, why not try a defaultdict(list) to append the values to the right letter at the time of making the list of tuples. Then you can simply sum them. See example below.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> val_store = defaultdict(list)
>>> # next lines are me simulating the creation of the tuple
>>> val_store['A'].append(10)
>>> val_store['B'].append(20)
>>> val_store['C'].append(30)
>>> val_store
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'C': [30], 'A': [10], 'B': [20]})
>>> val_store['A'].append(10)
>>> val_store['C'].append(30)
>>> val_store['B'].append(20)
>>> val_store
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'C': [30, 30], 'A': [10, 10], 'B': [20, 20]})

>>> for val in val_store:
...   print(val, sum(val_store[val]))
... 
C 60
A 20
B 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = [('A',100), ('B',50), ('A',50), ('B',20), ('C',10) ]

letters = set([s[0] for s in a])

new_a = []
for l in letters:
    nums = [s[1] for s in a if s[0] == l]
    new_a.append((l, sum(nums)))

print new_a
```

Results:

```
[('A', 150), ('C', 10), ('B', 70)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach

```
x = [('A',100),('B',50),('A',50),('B',20),('C',10)]
y = {}
for _tuple in x:
    if _tuple[0] in y:
        y[_tuple[0]] += _tuple[1]
    else:
        y[_tuple[0]] = _tuple[1]
print [(k,v) for k,v in y.iteritems()]
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner:

```
>>> x = [ ('A',100), ('B',50), ('A',50), ('B',20), ('C',10) ]
>>> {
...     k: reduce(lambda u, v: u + v, [y[1] for y in x if y[0] == k])
...     for k in [y[0] for y in x]
...     }.items()
[('A', 150), ('C', 10), ('B', 70)]
```