# Summarize the second elements in list of tuples if first elements are the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tuples, summary

HOW could Summarize the second elements in list of tuples,
if first elements are the same?

for example :

in this

```
lst = [('milk', '2.35'), ('bread', '1.95'), ('chips', '2.54'), 
       ('milk', '2.38'), ('milk', '2.31'), ('bread', '1.90')]
```

I would summarize second elements of milk together and
summarize second elements of bread together.

and return this list:

```
[('bread', '3.85'), ('chips', '2.54'), ('milk', '7.04')]

def my_def(a):
    my_list = []
    for item in a:
        if item[0] not in my_list:
            my_list.append(item[0])
    return my_list
```

I could just find same one :(

Comment: Use `itertools.groupby()`. But first, convert the number-like strings to numbers.

Comment: @DYZ they don't need groupby, they already have the grouping logic and the matching elements aren't actually consecutive in the source list.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Using an existing function is almost always preferable over custom logic. Naturally, the sequence shall be sorted before grouping.

Comment: Groupby works on sorted lists:  you can sort (and convert to floats) by `lst = sorted( (k,float(v)) for k,v in [('milk', '2.35'), ('bread', '1.95'), ('chips', '2.54'), ('milk', '2.38'), ('milk', '2.31'), ('bread', '1.90')])`

Answer (score 3):

You can summarize with a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of floats:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [('milk', '2.35'), ('bread', '1.95'), ('chips', '2.54'), ('milk', '2.38'), ('milk', '2.31'), ('bread', '1.90')]

d = defaultdict(float)
for x, y in l:
    d[x] += float(y)

print([(x, round(y, 2)) for x, y in d.items()])
# [('milk', 7.04), ('bread', 3.85), ('chips', 2.54)]
```

Comment: nice one - maybe better at one of the dupes.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks, I answered the question right as the dupe close went up, my bad. I feel like [stackoverflow.com/questions/39734549/sum-numbers-by-letter-in-list-of-tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734549/sum-numbers-by-letter-in-list-of-tuples) is a closer dupe though.

Comment: I dont mind answers below dupes .. there is a grace period and you can trick the clientsite evalutaion using developer tools if you feel like testing the "wrath" of mods. I added your dupe .. this question has about 10 to 15 at least ... it is quite common.